# Set getChildView() to return only selected rows

Tags: android

I have a BaseExpandableListAdapter class and getChildView() has to return only a couple rows. But, of course, returning null will crash the app and setting the visibility to GONE will create a blank space in the list.

So, the user has a checkbox in each row, and when one is checked the next time he opens the list it won't appear (like being deleted from the ArrayAdapter, but I can't do that).

Any good option?

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    int childrenCount = categories.get(groupPosition).size();
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    /** If the user wants to remove the completed items */
    if (settings.getBoolean("deleteCompletedItemsPref", false) == true) {
        for (int childPosition=0; childPosition<childrenCount; childPosition++) {
            if (categories.get(groupPosition).getItem(childPosition).isChecked()) {
                parent.removeViewAt(childPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    return childrenCount;
}
```

Here I run the group's children and try to remove the unwanted views, although I can't remove views here because is an AdapterView.

Answer (score 0):

your `BaseExpandableListAdapter` must have implemented a `getChildrenCount()` method. you can make it return the size of your category list (or maybe a copy of the list).

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return categories.get(groupPosition).size();
    }
```

Then simply remove the child position if it's checked (preferably in a click listener). Of course you'd also need to adjust your data set accordingly. perhaps make it an arraylist if it isn't then remove the same position in it.

Comment: I have everything as you said, that's not the problem. Following your logic of removing the unwanted rows: I can't remove them from onClick, the rows are to be removed when the view is created, that's why I wanted to do it in getChildView.

Comment: there's no reason you can't do it from `getChildView`. remove the position from what the `getChildrenCount` returns and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` perhaps post your code and we can see what's up.

Comment: That will not remove only the last line of the group?

Comment: i did not at all understand that last statement. it will remove whatever rows you need. are you in fact removing the corresponding child positions of your checkbox arraylist?

Comment: You said "remove the position from what the getChildrenCount returns", it returns the size. Maybe you should put some code, I'm not understanding your point...

Comment: maybe *you* should put some code. it returns the size as an `int` yes. which means that if you delete an index of the corresponding arraylist. the size will decrease. then the amount of rows will decrease because whatever this method returns is how many rows that the adapter will show.

Comment: I know that, but the method returns 4 if the size is 4, so it will delete always the last row. What I'm saying is I can't delete a X position from there. If I can please show me how.

Comment: this is why i said you "need to adjust your data set accordingly". it was 1/2 of the response. I used the categories array-list as an example because that's all your code provides but more ideal would be to make `getChildCount` return whatever your main data collection for the listview is and then remove from that.

Comment: Now I understood. I'll change my getChildCount and the problem would be solved. Thanks.